# Why “man” not “men” in “Many a brave man”?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement, many-a

I’m reading *Black Beauty* and there is a sentence there which starts like this:

> Many a brave man went down, many a horse fell,

Why *man* here? Why not *men*?

Answer (score 16):

The singular word "man" is used to agree with the determiner "a." [Learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-many-and-many-a) provides the following explanation for why an author might use "many" instead of "many a":

> The fixed expression *many a/an...* is more formal than the single
>   word *many*, and it is much less common. *Many a/an...* is used mainly
>   in literary writing and newspapers. Like the adjective and pronoun
>   many discussed above, *many a/an...* is used to indicate a large
>   number of something. However, it takes a singular noun, which can be
>   followed by a singular verb. Here are some examples:
>
> 1. It remained a mystery for *many a* year.  [=for many years]
> 2. I've been there *many a* time.  [=many times]
> 3. *Many a* politician has promised to make changes. [*Politician* and *has* are singular.]

Comment: These days, I don't think I'd call this "formal" but rather "poetic".  I wouldn't use it in formal non-fiction writing (reports, articles, etc).  I usually see it in period pieces, dramatic writing, songs, poems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, "many a something" is formal and old-fashioned and means a large number of people or things. The followings are some of the examples:
- Many a parent has had to go through this same painful process.
- I've sat here many a time (=often) and wondered what happened to her.